# How can I delete linked attachments from email in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, attachments

Using Thunderbird on Windows 10.  For most emails that have attachments, after I have saved the attachment, I still want to retain the email but lose the attachment.

Is there any way to delete the attached image or file?

I know I could just email it to myself.  But that loses the threaded conversation.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/1516834/delete-just-email-attachments) post has an answer that doesn't work on new Thunderbirds.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/220660/how-to-mass-remove-attachments-in-thunderbird-using-attachment-extractor) post is about the same addon/tool.

Comment: Two downvotes, care to say why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right-click on the attachment in the *Message Pane*.
- Click *Delete All...*.

[image: Delete All...]

Comment: I never knew there was a menu there.  I have always clicked to open or dragged it to store the attachment.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The *Delete All...* menu item exists, but has no effect. The *Detach All...* menu item saves separate copies of all the attachments, as expected, but fails to remove the attachments from the e-mail. Am I doing something wrong?